# MySQL で任意のタイムゾーンの当日0時の値を求めたい

Tags: mysql

timezone から当日0時の値を求めたいです
プログラムだと beggining_of_day とか mktime とかでできそうなのですが

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/date-and-time-functions.html

ここにある時間関数だけで
時刻以降を０にセットするというのが MySQL 関数だけでどう書けばいいのかわかりません

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Asia/Tokyo')
```

でタイムゾーン時刻は取得できるので
１度文字列に変換して substring をとって 00:00:00 をくっつけてからまた文字列をパースする
みたいなことをすればできなくはなさそうですが文字列を介すとなんとなく処理が重そうなので
１日分の秒数の MOD を取って引いたりとかでスマートにやる方法ってないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

処理が軽いかどうかはわからないのですが、次のような感じでできると思います。

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Asia/Tokyo')));
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMP(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'UTC', 'Asia/Tokyo'))) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2020-08-10 00:00:00                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`DATE()` で一旦日付に変換してから `TIMESTAMP()` で日時に変換してます。

Comment: なるほどです！　実装終わったら比較してパフォーマンス測ってみます！